# How can I add a extra roll of each columns' mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When I was using `df['mean'] = df.mean(axis = 1)`, it always added an extra COLUMN of average of each rows. But now I need an extra ROW to get each COLUMNS' mean. So I switch to `df['mean'] = df.mean(axis = 0)` but it still has an extra column but with all NaN. How can I get the row of each columns' average?

Here's the example ↓

[image: example]

Comment: Hi, could you please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay, ill edit this problem again! just a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(-1, 4), list('abcd'), list('ABCD'))

df.loc['mean', :] = df.mean(0)
df.loc[:, 'Mean'] = df.mean(1)
df.loc['mean', 'Mean'] = np.nan

df
```

[image]